# New Nav tabs not saving; new questions disappearing

Tags: bug, new-nav

The tab for "favorite tags" has been removed in the new navigation, so I made my own tab. It filters new questions to show only the ones with my favorite tabs, but it recently started glitching.

If I reload the page *or* swap to another tab and go back to my tab the tab becomes starred (*) and the Save button becomes available again, suggesting that the tab just got un-saved. (This part is pretty self explanatory, so I won't provide screenshots unless requested).

If I click the banner to show newer questions, (this happens around 60% of the time now) the new questions appear for a couple seconds, then 3 dots appear under the tag filter and the questions disappear. Rarely, older questions disappear as well. (See screenshots)

I'm getting this behavior on Safari 9 and Chrome "Version 47.0.2526.73 beta (64-bit)".

Screenshots below on Chrome:

Before clicking banner:
[image: Chrome before]

During:
[image: Chrome during]

After:
[image: Chrome after]

Comment: Why wasn't I alerted of this? I didn't get a notification saying that this was marked a duplicate.